# Overflow / math range error for log or exp

Tags: python, numpy, math, overflow

Line of code in question:

```
summing +=  yval * np.log(             sigmoid(np.dot(w.transpose(),xi.transpose()))) 
        +(1-yval)* np.log(max(0.001, 1-sigmoid(np.dot(w.transpose(),xi.transpose()))))
```

Error:

```
File "classify.py", line 67, in sigmoid
return 1/(1+ math.exp(-gamma))
OverflowError: math range error
```

The sigmoid function is just `1/(1+ math.exp(-gamma))`.

I'm getting a math range error. Does anyone see why?

Comment: Check the value of `gamma`.  If `-gamma` is greater than about 709, you'll get that error.

Comment: ... and in case it's unclear:  the "why" is, exp() uses a lot of range really fast

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106134/numpy-pure-functions-for-performance-caching/21106536#21106536 for some information about the sigmoid function in scipy.

Answer (score 15):

You can avoid this problem by using different cases for positive and negative gamma:

```
def sigmoid(gamma):
  if gamma < 0:
    return 1 - 1/(1 + math.exp(gamma))
  else:
    return 1/(1 + math.exp(-gamma))
```

The math range error is likely because your `gamma` argument is a large negative value, so you are calling `exp()` with a large positive value.  It is very easy to exceed your floating point range that way.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that, when `gamma` becomes large, `math.exp(gamma)` overflows. You can avoid this problem by noticing that

```
sigmoid(x) = 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
           = exp(x) / (exp(x) + 1)
           = 1 - 1 / (1 + exp(x))
           = 1 - sigmoid(-x)
```

This gives you a numerically stable implementation of `sigmoid` which guarantees you never even call `math.exp` with a positive value:

```
def sigmoid(gamma):
    if gamma < 0:
        return 1 - 1 / (1 + math.exp(gamma))
    return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-gamma))
```