# Deal with errors in parametrised sigmoid function in python

Tags: python, numpy, logistic-regression, sigmoid

I am trying to convert a set of numbers into sigmoids:

```
actualarray = {
    'open_cost_1':{
        'cost_matrix': [
            {'a': 24,'b': 56,'c': 78},
            {'a': 3,'b': 98,'c':1711},
            {'a': 121,'b': 12121,'c': 12989121},
        ]
    },
    'open_cost_2':{
        'cost_matrix': [
            {'a': 123,'b': 1312,'c': 1231},
            {'a': 1011,'b': 1911,'c':911},
            {'a': 1433,'b': 19829,'c': 1132},
        ]
    }
}
```

Where each number in each list of dicts in each `cost_matrix` gets normalised by different sigmoid functions:

```
def apply_normalizations(costs):

    def sigmoid(b,m,v):
        return ((np.exp(b+m*v) / (1 + np.exp(b+m*v)))*2)-1 #Taken from http://web.stanford.edu/class/psych252/tutorials/Tutorial_LogisticRegression.html

    def normalize_dicts_local_sigmoid(bias, slope,lst):
        return [{key: sigmoid(bias, slope,val) for key,val in dic.iteritems()} for dic in lst]


    for name, value in costs.items():
        if int((name.split("_")[-1]))>1:
            value['normalised_matrix_sigmoid'] = normalize_dicts_local_sigmoid(0,1,value['cost_matrix'])


 apply_normalizations(actualarray)
```

However, when I run this, I get:

```
 RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  return ((np.exp(b+m*v) / (1 + np.exp(b+m*v)))*2)-1
 RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  return ((np.exp(b+m*v) / (1 + np.exp(b+m*v)))*2)-1
```

And the array becomes:

```
{
    'open_cost_2': {
        'cost_matrix': [
            {
                'a': 123,
                'c': 1231,
                'b': 1312
            },
            {
                'a': 1011,
                'c': 911,
                'b': 1911
            },
            {
                'a': 1433,
                'c': 1132,
                'b': 19829
            }
        ],
        'normalised_matrix_sigmoid': [
            {
                'a': 1.0,
                'c': nan,
                'b': nan
            },
            {
                'a': nan,
                'c': nan,
                'b': nan
            },
            {
                'a': nan,
                'c': nan,
                'b': nan
            }
        ]
    },
    'open_cost_1': {
        'cost_matrix': [
            {
                'a': 24,
                'c': 78,
                'b': 56
            },
            {
                'a': 3,
                'c': 1711,
                'b': 98
            },
            {
                'a': 121,
                'c': 12989121,
                'b': 12121
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Note, every cost is always more than 0, hence I multiply by 2 and subtract 1 in my sigmoid function.

How can I adapt this to not have this error?

Comment: `return(RAM)  (RAM)/ (RAM)` Solution: Change your computer or leave working with `TEMP` values !

Comment: I don't quite get - is my function wrong? Can I replace nans with inf maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning states, the exponential in your implementation of the sigmoid function is overflowing.  When that happens, the function returns `nan`:

```
In [3]: sigmoid(1000, 1, 1)
/Users/warren/miniconda3/bin/ipython:2: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  if __name__ == '__main__':
/Users/warren/miniconda3/bin/ipython:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  if __name__ == '__main__':
Out[3]: nan
```

Instead of writing your sigmoid function in terms of `exp`, you can use [`scipy.special.expit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html).  It handles very large arguments correctly.

```
In [5]: from scipy.special import expit

In [6]: def mysigmoid(b, m, v):
   ...:     return expit(b + m*v)*2 - 1
   ...: 

In [7]: mysigmoid(1000, 1, 1)
Out[7]: 1.0
```

Check that it returns the same as your `sigmoid` function in cases where it doesn't overflow:

```
In [8]: sigmoid(1, 2, 3)
Out[8]: 0.99817789761119879

In [9]: mysigmoid(1, 2, 3)
Out[9]: 0.99817789761119879
```

See [Numpy Pure Functions for performance, caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106134/numpy-pure-functions-for-performance-caching/21106536#21106536) for my answer to another question about the sigmoid function.

Comment: Thanks @WarrenWeckesser. For the original function in my question, this is making every sigmoid value 0, even replacing the `'a': 1.0` value I had in my normalisation, the one that didn't normalise to `nan`. Logically all the very big numbers here should all make my sigmoid values 1 (given formula above) e.g. even `1231` should go to 1, not `nan` or 0.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem.  Could you give specific numerical values of `b`, `m` and `v` that don't give the value that you expect?  For example, using your function, `sigmoid(0, 1, 1231)` generates a warning and returns `nan`.   With my implementation, `mysigmoid(0, 1, 1231)` returns 1.0.

Comment: If you run my code above with the example , you will see what happens  - nothing goes to 1.0.

Comment: It works for me.  Did you *replace* your definition of `sigmoid()` with one that uses `expit`?

Comment: Yes, `def sigmoid(b,m,v):
        return ((expit(b+m*v) / (1 + expit(b+m*v)))*2)-1`

Comment: Please look at my definition of `mysigmoid()` again.  Don't replace `exp` with `expit`.  The return value is just `expit(b + m*v)*2 - 1`.

Comment: Did you mean that is the whole definition, not `return ((expit(b+m*v) / (1 + expit(b+m*v)))*2)-1`?

Comment: Yes.  See the code marked `In [6]` in my ipython session.  You would change the name to `sigmoid`, and use it instead of your current `sigmoid` function.