# Estimating logistic regression using BFGS optimization algorithm

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, logistic-regression, numerical-analysis

I tried to use `scipy.optimize.minimum` to estimate parameters in logistic regression. Before this, I wrote log likelihood function and gradient of log likelihood function. I then used **Nelder-Mead** and **BFGS** algorithm, respectively. *Turned out the latter one failed but the former one succeeded.* Because **BFGS** algorithm also uses the gradient, I doubt the gradient part (`function log_likelihood_gradient(x, y)`) suffers from bugs. But it's also likely due to any numerical issue associated with **Nelder-Mead** since I got the warning `Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.`

---

I'm using UCLA's tutorial and dataset (see [link](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/logit.htm)) and the correct estimates are,

[image]

FYI, I also highly suggest you reading this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203740/logistic-regression-scikit-learn-vs-statsmodels) to understand the problem setup and preprocess on the dataset.

---

Now is my code, the first part is data preparation. You can simply run it to get yourself a copy,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from patsy import dmatrices

from urllib.request import urlretrieve
url = 'http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv'
urlretrieve(url, './admit_rate.csv')
data = pd.read_csv('./admit_rate.csv')

y, x = dmatrices('admit ~ gre + gpa + C(rank)', data, return_type = 'dataframe')
y = np.array(y, dtype=np.float64)
x = np.array(x, dtype=np.float64)
```

---

The second part is the MLE part, `log_likelihood` defines the sum of log-likelihood function, and `log_likelihood_gradient` defines the gradient of the sum of log-likelihood function. Both come from the formula as below,
[image]

```
def sigmoid(x):
    """
    Logistic function
    """
    return 1.0 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    """
    Logistic function's first derivative
    """
    return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))

def log_likelihood(x, y):
    """
    The sum of log likelihood functions
    """
    n1, n2 = x.shape
    def log_likelihood_p(p):
        """
        p: betas/parameters in logistic regression, to be estimated
        """
        p = p.reshape(n2, 1)
        sig = sigmoid(np.dot(x, p)).reshape(n1, 1)
        return np.sum(y * np.log(sig) + (1 - y) * np.log(1 - sig)) 
    return log_likelihood_p
 
def log_likelihood_gradient(x, y):
    """
    The gradient of the sum of log likelihood functions used in optimization
    """
    n1, n2 = x.shape
    def log_likelihood_gradient_p(p):
        """
        p: betas/parameters in logistic regression, to be estimated
        """
        p = p.reshape(n2, 1)
        xp = np.dot(x, p)
        sig = sigmoid(xp)
        sig_der = sigmoid_derivative(xp)
        return np.sum(y * sig_der / sig * x - (1 - y) * sig_der / (1 - sig) * x, axis=0)
    return log_likelihood_gradient_p

def negate(f):  
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: -f(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

The third part is the optimization part, I started with inital value

***x0 = np.array([-1, -0.5, -1, -1.5, 0, 1])***

for **Nelder-Mead**, it works and outputs

***array([ -3.99005691e+00,  -6.75402757e-01,  -1.34021420e+00, -1.55145450e+00,   2.26447746e-03,   8.04046227e-01]***.

But then when I tried **Nelder-Mead** algorithm, it failed at

***x0 = np.array([-1, -0.5, -1, -1.5, 0, 1])***.

Even when I gave even closer initial value like the output from **Nelder-Mead** algorithm, it failed with warning `Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss`.

**Nelder-Mead**

```
x0 = np.array([-1, -0.5, -1, -1.5, 0, 1])
estimator1 = minimize(negate(log_likelihood(x, y)), x0, 
               method='nelder-mead', options={'disp': True})
print(estimator1.success)
estimator1.x
```

**BFGS**

```
x0 = np.array([ -3.99005691e+00,  -6.75402757e-01,  -1.34021420e+00,
        -1.55145450e+00,   2.26447746e-03,   8.04046227e-01])
estimator2 = minimize(negate(log_likelihood(x, y)), x0, method='BFGS', 
                     jac=log_likelihood_gradient(x, y), options={'disp': True})
print(estimator2.success)
```

---

I know my post is a bit long, but I'd glad to answer for any questions you throw to me and can anyone help?

Comment: Sometimes a better initial guess will work.  Try, say, `[1, 0.01, 1, -1, -1, -1]` (assuming the columns are intercept, gre, gpa, rank2, rank3, rank4).  If that doesn't work, try something even closer to the known solution.  Of course, you can't do that in general, but in this case, if it works, you'll know you don't have any egregious errors in your code.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Really appreciate your enlightening comment. I changed initial value to `x0 = np.array([-1, -0.5, -1, -1.5, 0, 1])` and this worked for **Nelder-Mead** but still failed for **BFGS** method. So I guess either the gradient function (since only **BFGS** uses gradient) or some numerical issue associated with **BFGS** went wrong. I have re-edited my post based on your suggestion.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser While the **Nelder-Mead** has worked now, I think this method is probably not perfect for the problem since even for a-not-that faraway initial guess, it fails easily. As for the **BFGS** method, do you think it's because the introduction of the exponential function and the derivative making the problem break easily numerically? Maybe I should use symbolic operation?

Comment: I haven't run your code.  I implemented a least-squares estimator with initial guess [-1, 0.1, 1, -1, -1, -1] for intercept, gre, gpa, rank2, rank3, rank4,  and used that result as the initial guess for the MLE.   That works using Nelder-Mead for the least-squares solver, and either Nelder-Mead or Powell for the MLE problem.  (I didn't implement the Jacobian, and I didn't try other solvers.)  To compute the sigmoid, I used `scipy.special.expit`; see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106134/numpy-pure-functions-for-performance-caching/21106536#21106536 for more information.

Comment: I should also add that to compute the log-likelihood, I used `xlogy` and `xlog1py` from `scipy.special`: `log_likelihood = np.sum(xlogy(y, sig) + xlog1py((1 - y), -sig)) `.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't implement the Jacobian (not to mention Hessian matrix), it works pretty well using Nelder-Mead and Powell. However,it seems the only problem here is **Jacobian**. I changed my `sigmoid_derivative()` to your `logistic._pdf()` since it handles overflow much better. I also changed to your `log_likelihood`. But if I take derivative on your `log_likelihood`, the hell break loose again! I print some intermediate values and it seems the problem is due to overflow. I challenge you writing your own Jacobian.

Comment: For now I doubt unless we standardize the data, we can never solve it using Jacobian to speed up the optimization:(