# Overflow Error in Python's numpy.exp function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I want to use `numpy.exp` like this:

```
cc = np.array([
    [0.120,0.34,-1234.1]
])

print 1/(1+np.exp(-cc))
```

But this gives me error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:5: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
```

I can't understand why? How can I fix this? It seems the problem is with third number `(-1234.1)`

Comment: For a discussion of the sigmoid function, see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106134/numpy-pure-functions-for-performance-caching (TL;DR:  Use [`scipy.special.expit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html))

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As fuglede says, the issue here is that `np.float64` can't handle a number as large as `exp(1234.1)`. Try using `np.float128` instead:

```
>>> cc = np.array([[0.120,0.34,-1234.1]], dtype=np.float128)
>>> cc
array([[ 0.12,  0.34, -1234.1]], dtype=float128)
>>> 1 / (1 + np.exp(-cc))
array([[ 0.52996405,  0.58419052,  1.0893812e-536]], dtype=float128)
```

Note however, that there are certain quirks with using extended precision. It may not work on Windows; you don't actually get the full 128 bits of precision; and you might lose the precision whenever the number passes through pure python. You can read more about the details [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html#extended-precision).

For most practical purposes, you can probably approximate `1 / (1 + <a large number>)` to zero. That is to say, just ignore the warning and move on. Numpy takes care of the approximation for you (when using `np.float64`):

```
>>> 1 / (1 + np.exp(-cc))
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  #!/usr/local/bin/python3.4
array([[ 0.52996405,  0.58419052,  0.        ]])
```

If you want to suppress the warning, you could use [`scipy.special.expit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html), as suggested by WarrenWeckesser in a comment to the question:

```
>>> from scipy.special import expit
>>> expit(cc)
array([[ 0.52996405,  0.58419052,  0.        ]])
```

Answer (score 22):

The largest value representable by a `numpy` float is 1.7976931348623157e+308, whose logarithm is about 709.782, so there is no way to represent `np.exp(1234.1)`.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.finfo('d').max
Out[2]: 1.7976931348623157e+308

In [3]: np.log(_)
Out[3]: 709.78271289338397

In [4]: np.exp(709)
Out[4]: 8.2184074615549724e+307

In [5]: np.exp(710)
/usr/local/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  #!/usr/local/bin/python3.5
Out[5]: inf
```

Comment: BTW, `exp(1234.1)` is equal to `9.17952305220754e+535`.

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution is to use the `decimal` module, which lets you work with arbitrary precision floats. Here is an example where a `numpy` array of floats with 100 digits precision is used:

```
import numpy as np
import decimal

# Precision to use
decimal.getcontext().prec = 100

# Original array
cc = np.array(
    [0.120,0.34,-1234.1]
)
# Fails
print(1/(1 + np.exp(-cc)))    

# New array with the specified precision
ccd = np.asarray([decimal.Decimal(el) for el in cc], dtype=object)
# Works!
print(1/(1 + np.exp(-ccd)))
```

Comment: Do you lose the advantage of vectorized operations when working with decimal? I'd guess that since numpy would have to treat it as an object, you  might implicitly lose speed?

Comment: You loose a lot of speed indeed. Actually, `numpy` delegates the entire computation to the `Decimal` objects, operations on which cannot be performed natively by your CPU. For a large array the time difference will be severe.

Answer (score 3):

exp(-1234.1) is too small for 32bit or 64bit floating-point numbers. Since it cannot be represented, numpy produces the correct warning.

Using `IEEE 754 32bit floating-point` numbers, the smallest positive number it can represent is `2^(-149)`, which is roughly 1e-45.

If you use `IEEE 754 64 bit floating-point` numbers, the smallest positive number is `2^(-1074)` which is roughy 1e-327.

In either case, it cannot represent a number as small as exp(-1234.1) which is about 1e-535.

You should be using the `expit` function from scipy to compute the sigmoid function. This would give you better precision.

For practical purposes, exp(-1234.1) is a very small number. If rounding to zero makes sense in your use case, numpy produces benign results by rounding it to zero.

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t care about precision, you can use `numpy.clip`.

In `float64`:

```
cc = np.clip(cc, -709.78, 709.78)
```

In `float32`:

```
cc = np.clip(cc, -88.72, 88.72)
```

Answer (score 1):

This overflow can be handled mathematically; you may not need to convert your values to `np.float128`

A sigmoid function is defined by:

[image]

Now, when you rearrange this function by multiplying numerator and denominator by `e**x`.

You will get:

[image]

So, you can design your sigmoid function accordingly:

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
  if x > 0:   
    z = np.exp(-x)
    return 1/(1+z)
  else:
    z = np.exp(x)
    return z/(1+z)
```

---

Coming back to the question:

```
cc = np.array([0.120,0.34,-1234.1])
print([sigmoid(x) for x in cc])

#output
[0.5299640517645717, 0.5841905229354074, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier by [Praveen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/525169/praveen), you can use `expit` from `scipy`

So the problem can be solved by using: 1 / (1+ exp(-x)) = exp(x) / (1+exp(x))

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> cc = np.array([[0.120,0.34,-1234.1]])
>>> np.exp(cc) / (1 +  np.exp(cc))
array([[0.52996405, 0.58419052, 0.        ]])
```