# Code working fine on jupyter but won't work in script

Tags: python, numpy

I have a project that requires EDA of time-series data, while in jupyter it works fine (and it also takes much less time to load data in jupyter)

What i want to do after these is to graph out the data of a individual SKU (item id), I tried to code out a GUI with JS and use plotly to visualize data, here is the function:

```py
    @eel.expose
    def boxPlot():
        N = 12   # Number of boxes
        c = ['hsl('+str(h)+',50%'+',50%)' for h in np.linspace(0, 360, N)]
        months = data_sku['month'].values
        print(data_sku)
        month_name = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
        fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Box(
            name = month_name[i],
            y=np.expm1(np.around(data_sku[data_sku.month==int(months[i])]['Total Revenue'].values,decimals=2)),
            marker_color=c[i]
            ) for i in range(int(N))])

        fig.update_layout(
            title='Total Revenue Distribution for SKU:'+str(list(sku_to_int.keys())[list(sku_to_int.values()).index(sku_num)]),
            xaxis=dict(showgrid=True, zeroline=True, showticklabels=True),
            yaxis=dict(zeroline=True, gridcolor='white'),
        )
        fig.show()
        aPlot = plotly.offline.plot(fig,output_type='div',include_plotlyjs=False)
        return aPlot
```

Where the value passed into np.expm1 is a float64 numpy array

This function prints out a box plot of Total Revenue distributed through months for that given item or SKU. But every time i try to run this on VSCode or just by command line, I get this error:

> ...\app\main.py:28: RuntimeWarning:
>
> overflow encountered in expm1

Comment: Have you tried cutting this down (or building up from scratch) to isolate your problem? You have a lot going on. What is the value of `np.around(data_sku[data_sku.month==int(months[i])]['Total Revenue'].values,decimals=2)` ?

Comment: hey there, this just limits the decimal number after the floating point for every value in matrix. I thought maybe this would help to overcome the error but it hasn't.

Comment: Still, what is the value being passed into `np.expm1`? I see other SO questions about this same issue and the answers are to change the value type (float64 -> float128)

Comment: it's a numpy array of type=float64. Is there a float128 type?

Comment: `x = np.array({your_array_here}, dtype=np.float128)`

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same python (and numpy etc) installation in Jupyter as in the command line?  Might be worth doing a `print(sys.version)` or two to make sure.

Comment: @CurtF. yes they're the same version. When i try to convert it to float128, I get this error: " module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float128' ".

Comment: Are you using windows? float128 is too much precision

Comment: yes, I am on windows. Weird thing is, it works on jupyter...

Comment: It appears your problem is not related to `eel`, `plotly`, or `plotly-python` -- you can remove those tags from your question. 

I'd like the question to be edited to show only the values being passed into `np.expm1`, as that's the error in question.

Other SO questions have answers about exp overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726490/overflow-error-in-pythons-numpy-exp-function