# Python power operator in a loop: strange output values after a certain element

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, exponential

I identified a strange behaviour of the ** operator. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

n = np.arange(0,20)

print(np.c_[n,10 **n])
```

I obtain the following output:

```
array([[                   0,                    1],
       [                   1,                   10],
       [                   2,                  100],
       [                   3,                 1000],
       [                   4,                10000],
       [                   5,               100000],
       [                   6,              1000000],
       [                   7,             10000000],
       [                   8,            100000000],
       [                   9,           1000000000],
       [                  10,          10000000000],
       [                  11,         100000000000],
       [                  12,        1000000000000],
       [                  13,       10000000000000],
       [                  14,      100000000000000],
       [                  15,     1000000000000000],
       [                  16,    10000000000000000],
       [                  17,   100000000000000000],
       [                  18,  1000000000000000000],
       [                  19, -8446744073709551616]])
```

I do not understand the reason of the out for n=19.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726490/overflow-error-in-pythons-numpy-exp-function

Comment: Hint: Try adding a `print(type(n[0]))` line.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by @Ankur Ankan, this is an overflow error, you can check [numpy data types](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html) to see the range of each type. 
For example change the `dtype` to `np.uint64` will cover the whole array

```
n = np.arange(0,20).astype(np.uint64)
print(np.c_[n,10**n])
[[                   0                    1]
 [                   1                   10]
 [                   2                  100]
 [                   3                 1000]
 [                   4                10000]
 [                   5               100000]
 [                   6              1000000]
 [                   7             10000000]
 [                   8            100000000]
 [                   9           1000000000]
 [                  10          10000000000]
 [                  11         100000000000]
 [                  12        1000000000000]
 [                  13       10000000000000]
 [                  14      100000000000000]
 [                  15     1000000000000000]
 [                  16    10000000000000000]
 [                  17   100000000000000000]
 [                  18  1000000000000000000]
 [                  19 10000000000000000000]]
```