# How to fit exponential function with the python?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit an exponential function of the form y = e^(-b/x)in python. The data I'm using looks like this

[image]

But when I try to plot I'm getting this error
"RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
if **name** == '**main**':"

Here is my code

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

""" Fitting Function"""
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a *np.exp(-1*b/x) 
data = np.loadtxt("S005_CP_0011_N20.dat", skiprows=1)
xData, yData = np.hsplit(data,2)
x = xData[:,0]
y = yData[:,0]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
mpl.plot(x, func(x, *popt), label="Fitted Curve")
mpl.legend(loc='upper left')
mpl.show()
```

Could someone please help to rectify the code?

Comment: In the question your exponent scales with `-1/x` but in your code it's `-x`. Which one is correct?

Comment: yes, you're correct its -(b/x). But still, I'm not getting the desired fit. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: is `S005_CP_0011_N20.dat` available somewhere?

Comment: @Mahesh What's the fit you are getting? It's possible your data is too noisy. Also cut the data to start when the exponential decay begins and ends, otherwise the empty data at the start will effect the fit. It's highly possible the reason for your linear fit is that `curve_fit` is failing to fit it as a whole, resulting in b-> 0.

Comment: @MarijnvanVliet Yes, I have it but I don't know how to share with you??

Comment: @ZWang That nice point I will try to do that.

Comment: @ZWang I cut the noisy data but but now I'm getting the error "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  if __name__ == '__main__':" ,

Comment: Have you printed popt to see if the fit results are anything reasonable?

Comment: Note that your function defines an argument `c`, yet this is nowhere used inside the actual function.

Comment: It's probably best to provide some starting estimate for `a` and `b` through the `p0` parameter of `curve_fit`.

Comment: I do not see well your axis, but do you have any negative value? Is so, try to replace them by 0+ or anything else that do not alter too much the tendency.

Comment: @Mahesh that's because the number is too large for np.float64 to handle. Try changing to np.float(128). For more information, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726490/overflow-error-in-pythons-numpy-exp-function

Comment: @Mahesh The function does not match the data, I guess you expect an exponential decay, e.g `a*np.exp(-b*x)`. Also, provide an initial guess for the parameters a,b, otherwise curve_fit will try with both parameters set to 0 which is not defined when using your function.