# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp Python/Scipy

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm a total beginner in using curve_fit() of scipy. I don't understand what the problem is in the following code of mine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

xdata = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22]
ydata = [75,66,63,61,60,58,58,55,56,54,56,59,57,57,56,58,56,58,56,56,56]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
```

It returns RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp

Any idea what could be wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably worth putting in a print statement into `func` to see what arguments it is being called with.

Comment: @JohanC that didnt help unfortunately

Comment: @Derlin unfortunately neither, I had seen that one before

Answer (score 4):

As remarked in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726490/overflow-error-in-pythons-numpy-exp-function), `np.exp` quickly reaches overflow.  You can avoid the overflow with adding [bounds](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) on `b`. Note that you only get a warning, and that the result of `curve_fit` isn't affected.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

xdata = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
ydata = [75, 66, 63, 61, 60, 58, 58, 55, 56, 54, 56, 59, 57, 57, 56, 58, 56, 58, 56, 56, 56]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, bounds=([-np.inf, 0.0001, -np.inf], [np.inf, 10, np.inf]))
xs = np.linspace(2, 22, 100)
plt.plot(xs, func(xs, *popt))
plt.scatter(xdata, ydata)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: Also note that the fitted function uses the datatype of `x`, which sometimes causes strange problems. In this example there isn't problem, but in general it could help to add `xdata = np.array(xdata, dtype=float)` or `xdata = np.array(xdata, dtype=np.longdouble)`.