# how to solve ValueError "Residuals are not finite in the initial point" on scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I want to fit an exponential function to some points using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` ([documentation here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)). But I always get this `ValueError: Residuals are not finite in the initial point`

Here are my points:

```
x = np.linspace(2011, 2021, 11)
y = np.array([2307, 4541, 7114, 12156, 18948, 25502, 34022, 53861, 83175, 136617, 309083])
```

When I plot the data, it looks like this:

[image]

Looks like an exponential function. Thats why I try to fit it with this function:

```
def y_func(x, a, b, c):
    return np.exp(c*(x-2011))*b +a
```

When I call

```
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curvefit(y_func, y, x)
```

I get a `RuntimeError:Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800`. I have tried setting `maxfev` to a higher value, but that didn't solve it.

I have figured out some parameters on my own: `a=2307`, `b=50`, `c=0.88` by playing arround. Not perfect, but at least a guess. Looks like this:

[image]

- I have tried all the available `methods` (see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html))
- I have tried providing `bounds` for the parameters
- I have tried providing an initial guess `p0` for the parameters

Now I end up with this:

```
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(y_func, y, x, bounds=([1000, 30, 0.8], [3000, 80, 1.1]),
                                      p0=[2307, 50, 0.88])
```

And I only get this: `ValueError: Residuals are not finite in the initial point`

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overflow Error in Python's numpy.exp function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726490/overflow-error-in-pythons-numpy-exp-function). When I tried running this, I got `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp` which led me to that question.

Comment: You have swapped `y` and `x` in your call to `curve_fit`.

Comment: @Patol75 : yes, you are right, what a dumb mistake, thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Zev: thanks for the link, I will also keep this in mind!