# Overflow encountered in exp during calculation with large physics constants

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np




def BB_RAD(wavelength, T, d_lambda):

    c = 3 * 1E8 * 1E9 
    h = 6.626 * 1E-34
    k_B = 1.380649 * 1E-23

    X = (h*c)/(wavelength * k_B * T)
    
    u_lambda = ((2 * (np.pi) * (c**2) * h)/(wavelength**5)) *(1/(np.exp(X) - 1))
    f = u_lambda * d_lambda
    
    return f
    

wavelength = np.linspace(1,10000, 1000)
d_lambda = wavelength[2] - wavelength[1]
T = 26 + 273

E_lambda = BB_RAD(wavelength, T, d_lambda)
```

```
BB_Radiation.py:14: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
   u_lambda = ((2 * (np.pi) * (c**2) * h)/(wavelength**5)) *(1/(np.exp(X)- 1))
```

I request if anybody could kindly tell me why is this error being projected ? I was trying to plot Thermal radiation density versus wavelength plot.

Comment: Could you provide the values of `c`, `h`, `wavelength`, and most importantly `X`, that you used when you got this error? For instance, add `print(c,h,wavelength,X)` just before the line that gets this error, and show the result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overflow Error in Python's numpy.exp function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726490/overflow-error-in-pythons-numpy-exp-function)

Comment: And this paragraph holds here too: *"For most practical purposes, you can probably approximate 1 / (1 + <a large number>) to zero. That is to say, just ignore the warning and move on. Numpy takes care of the approximation for you (when using np.float64):"*

Comment: No no no, please edit your question with the values, don't post them in the comments it's unreadable

Comment: @Stef, actually, as I am compiling then code in linux (python-3) this output is merely projected on screen so could not run further.

Comment: Well, now that I see your values, I think there is a simple fix. Remove all the `1E8`, `1E9`, `1E-34` from your values; compute the result without this; and count the exponents on the side (as if they were part of the unit).

Comment: @Stef OK, that sounds better to scale. Thanks