Running into Python Warnings in Molecular Simulations
I am building a molecular simulation of liquid water at 295.4 K using the central force model (https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/63/12/5223/216135/Study-of-a-central-force-model-for-liquid-water-by). I am able to run everything but I encounter issues when it comes to using the run function itself. It strange because all of the functions work individually. I usually get "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp","RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power", and so forth. Many of the problems occur in these functions below.
#@njit
def calculate_forces(positions_O, positions_H,mass_O, mass_H, box_length, rcut2, ecut_OO, ecut_OH, ecut_HH):
    '''
    Calculate the forces acting on of the particles

    Parameters
    ----------
    positions : numpy.ndarray(dtype=np.float64, shape=(N_particles, 3))
        The current positions of the particles
    box_length : np.float64
        The length of the box
    rcut2 : np.float64
        The distance cutoff
    ecut : np.float64
        The energy shift

    Returns
    -------
    forces : numpy.ndarray(dtype=float, shape=(N_particles, 3))
        The current forces acting on each of the particles
    potential_energy : np.float64
        The total potential energy
    '''
    forces_O = np.zeros_like(positions_O)
    forces_H = np.zeros_like(positions_H)
    #force_H = np.zeros_like(positions_H)
    potential_energy=0
    
    # Loop through O-O
    for i in range(positions_O.shape[0]-1): 
        for j in range(i+1, positions_O.shape[0]):
            r = positions_O[i]-positions_O[j] # distance vector
            r = r - (box_length*np.round(r/box_length)) # Periodic boundary conditions
            r2 = np.sum(r**2)

            if r2 < rcut2: # If within cutoff distance
                # Calculate force between particles
                #force_vec_OO = -36.1345/r**2 - ((800*np.exp(40(x-2)))/(1+np.exp(40(x-2))**2))+259.0695*np.exp(-7.60626(x-1.4525)**2)*(x-1.4525)
                force_vec_OO = 144.538/r**2 + 196405.12613/r**9.3927
                # Add force between pair to net force on each particle
                forces_O[i] = forces_O[i] + force_vec_OO
                forces_O[j] = forces_O[j] - force_vec_OO
                # Add potential energy of interaction to total potential energy 
                potential_energy += V_OO(r) - ecut_OO


        #Loop Through H-H
        for i in range(positions_H.shape[0]-1): 
            for j in range(i+1, positions_H.shape[0]):
                r = positions_H[i]-positions_H[j] # distance vector
                r = r - (box_length*np.round(r/box_length)) # Periodic boundary conditions
                r2 = np.sum(r**2)
    
                if r2 < rcut2: # If within cutoff distance
                    # Calculate force between particles
                    
                    force_vec_HH = 36.1345/r**2 + ((800*np.exp(40*(r-2)))/(1+np.exp(40*(r-2))**2))-259.0695*np.exp(-7.60626*(r-1.4525)**2)
                    
                    # Add force between pair to net force on each particle
                    forces_H[i] = forces_H[i] + force_vec_HH
                    forces_H[j] = forces_H[j] - force_vec_HH
                    # Add potential energy of interaction to total potential energy 
                    potential_energy += V_HH(r) - ecut_HH

        #Loop Through OH
        for i in range(positions_O.shape[0]-1): 
            for j in range(i+1, positions_H.shape[0]):
                r = positions_O[i]-positions_H[j] # distance vector
                r = r - (box_length*np.round(r/box_length)) # Periodic boundary conditions
                r2 = np.sum(r**2)
    
                if r2 < rcut2: # If within cutoff distance
                    # Calculate force between particles
                    #force_vec_OH = 72.269/x**2 - 36.935469/x**15.97 + 32.9583*np.exp(5.49305(x-2.2))
                    force_vec_OH = -72.269/r**2 + 36.935469/r**15.97 - (32.9583*np.exp(5.49305*(r-2.2)))/(1+np.exp(5.49305*(r-2.2)))**2
                    # Add force between pair to net force on each particle
                    forces_O[i] = forces_O[i] + force_vec_OH 
                    forces_H[j] = forces_H[j] - force_vec_OH
                    # Add potential energy of interaction to total potential energy 
                    potential_energy += V_OH(r) - ecut_OH
            
        forces_O = forces_O/mass_O
        forces_H = forces_H/mass_H
    return forces_O, forces_H, potential_energy



and in
V_HH = lambda r: 36.1345/r + 20/(1+np.exp(40*(r-2))) - 17.03002*np.exp(-7.60626*((r-1.4525)**2))
V_OH = lambda r: -72.269/r+2.6677/r**14.97 - 6/(1+np.exp(5.49305*(r-2.2)))
V_OO = lambda r: 144.538/r + 23401.9/(r**8.3927)

def get_cutparams(box_length):
    rcut = box_length/2
    ecut_OO = V_OO(rcut)
    ecut_OH = V_OH(rcut)
    ecut_HH = V_HH(rcut)

    rcut2 = rcut**2

    return rcut2, ecut_OO, ecut_OH, ecut_HH

I have tried changing the datatype to float128 to accommodate and making sure all of the functions are correct.

The value of np.exp in your calculation is larger than the default maximum limit. Please check this thread which might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726490/overflow-error-in-pythons-numpy-exp-function. Since you already tried float128, maybe check other answers also.
