# what is the fastest way to calculate sigmoid?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, sigmoid

I am trying to implement a recurrent neural network where `sigmoid` is chosen to be the activation function.

My first prototype is written in `python` and I find `sigmoid` is somehow the bottleneck of the program, accounts for ~30% of the total running time.

```
# x is a fixed size vector here
def sigmoid(x):
    return numpy.reciprocal(1.0 + numpy.exp(-x))
```

So I tried another implementation

```
def sigmoid(x):
    y = numpy.exp(x)
    return y/(1+y)
```

and surprisingly found it is 50% faster than the first approach.

I also tried a third approach

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return (1.0+numpy.tanh(x/2.0))/2.0
```

, which is slightly slower than the first approach.

Later I tested all 3 implementations in C++. The first two approach has barely any difference, and `tanh` is slightly (~5%) faster. Why does this happen? I am thinking `numpy` was written in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106134/numpy-pure-functions-for-performance-caching) it seems your best bet is [`scipy.special.expit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html)