# numpy apply_over_axis applies function to each element and not on 1-D slices

Tags: python, numpy

here is an example

```
import numpy as np
ds = np.random.rand(1600, 133)

def sigmoid(z):
    s = 1 / (1 + (1 / np.exp(z)))
return s

np.apply_along_axis(sigmoid, 0, ds).shape
```

output

```
(1600, 133)
```

I would expect to see a result of shape `(133,)`. Somehow numpy decides that this function cannot be applied to a column (?) or where am I going wrong in using it?

Comment: Your `sigmoid` function doesn't reduce the number of elements, so you wouldn't expect the column to be collapsed. Try `np.apply_along_axis(np.sum, 0, ds).shape`

Comment: But that doesn't seem to be a hard requirement for when a function can be applied to a vector. I would assume that it should first try to do the mapping in slices.

Comment: It's not a hard requirement. But you expect differently when the functions applied are different.

Comment: ops my bad, #Kamin is correct, I don't know why I was expecting to see a shape like that

Comment: Since sigmoid returns a vector of the same size

Comment: The code use `apply_along_axis` but the subject line is `apply_over_axis`.  It might help if you demonstrated what you wanted with a simple iteration over one axis or other.  With a 2d array these `apply...` functions don't add much functionality.  And they don't add any speed with any size array.

Comment: Off-topic, just FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106134/numpy-pure-functions-for-performance-caching/21106536#21106536

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the function you are using (sigmoid) is returning 1D-array. The shape of output is the same as the shape of input (1-D slice). If you would like to get (133,) array as an output your function would have to return single number.