# python warning exception without stopping program

Tags: python, numpy, overflow

I just got this error while doing a neural network, this error arise when I pass my nodes in my activation function (sigmoid), I suspect the error arise because its a convolutionnal neural network and so the convolutional layer uses ReLU as an activation function which can make numbers really big; in my sigmoid function:

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoidprime(x):
    return np.exp(-x) / ((1 + np.exp(-x))**2)
```

in the function, x is my nodes, but sometime the number can get really big and since the sigmoid function is effectively only usefull between 0 and 1, I believe this is what raise the error BUT when I try it with a single really big number it does not raise the error, plus, the error doesnt actually stop my program. What I want to know is how to prevent the exception and if my activation function is passed even if the error is raised

> Warning (from warnings module):
>     File "C:\Python27\saves\CNN\CNN_flat_layer.py", line 17
>       return np.exp(-x) / ((1 + np.exp(-x))**2)
>   RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
>
> Warning (from warnings module):
>     File "C:\Python27\saves\CNN\CNN_flat_layer.py", line 17
>       return np.exp(-x) / ((1 + np.exp(-x))**2)
>   RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
>
> Warning (from warnings module):
>     File "C:\Python27\saves\CNN\CNN_flat_layer.py", line 17
>       return np.exp(-x) / ((1 + np.exp(-x))**2)
>   RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106134/numpy-pure-functions-for-performance-caching/21106536#21106536) to a question about the sigmoid function and its derivative.

Comment: *"when I try it with a single really big number it does not raise the error"*  What number did you try?  To trigger overflow, you would need a negative number with large absolute value.

Comment: I tried huge numbers like 10000000, althought I checked my nodes and when it comes to the function, most numbers are under 5000

Comment: just tried and I confirm huge negative number does trigger the warning without actually breaking anything, it just returns 0

Comment: any idea how to prevent the error of showing up since it does the job anyway?

Comment: You could use `scipy.special.expit` and the function `sigmoid_grad_sech2` from the answer I linked above.  They don't generate a warning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160746/discussion-between-tissuebox-and-warren-weckesser).

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, the first warning is the one to note. If the absolute value of `x` is very small or large than the result of `np.exp(x)` is likely larger or smaller than what its dtype can hold. The fact that it is an overflow error indicates this is most likely what is happening