# sigmoid RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, floating-point

I'm trying to create a sigmoid function in Python, however, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
```

Here my code:

```
def sigmoid(self, value):

    a = np.exp(-value)
    return 1.0/ (1.0 + a)
```

I searched for previous answers, but they didn't solve my problem.
The problem is on calculating the value of a.
I also tried using:

`a = np.float128(np.exp(-value))`

but I got the same error, and using:

`a = np.float256(np.exp(-value))`

I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'float256'
```

I thought that if I have an overflow I could return 0, and if I have an underflow I could return 1

Comment: `print(sys.float_info)` gives you the maximal and minimal value a float number can have. You might also want to read up on [numpy data types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) and their limitations.

Comment: What's your python and numpy version?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106134/numpy-pure-functions-for-performance-caching/21106536#21106536

Answer (score 7):

A warning is not an error. You *could* just ignore it.

That said, it happens when the result of `exp(-value)` exceeds the maximum number representable by `value`'s floating point data type format.

You can prevent the overflow by checking if `value` is too small:

```
def sigmoid(value):
    if -value > np.log(np.finfo(type(value)).max):
        return 0.0    
    a = np.exp(-value)
    return 1.0/ (1.0 + a)
```

Comment: is it better to clip to upper bound of sigmoid = 1.0  , instead of 0.0 ?

Comment: ValueError: data type <class 'numpy.object_'> not inexact