# Sigmoid Activation Function: ValueError data type not inexact / RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, activation-function

I encountered *" RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp "* while implementing Sigmoid in my code.

I tried to solved it by using this solution 
[sigmoid RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48540589/sigmoid-runtimewarning-overflow-encountered-in-exp) .
Nonetheless, now a new error occurs on the if-condition.

Here the code that I tried:

```
class Sigmoid:
    @staticmethod
    def activation(x):
        if -x > np.log(np.finfo(type(x)).max):
            return 0.0
        a = np.exp(-x)
        return 1.0 / (1.0 + a)
```

So this error arises:

```
File "/MyPathCode/", line 14 in activation
   if -x > np.log(np.finfo(type(x)).max):
File "/home/UserName/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py", line 381, in __new__
    raise ValueError("data type %r not inexact" % (dtype))
ValueError: data type <class 'numpy.object_'> not inexact
```