# Exp function overflows and type casting does not work

Tags: python, numpy

I keep getting this error for sigmoid function

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-s))

def sigmoid(s):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-s))
```

I tried fixing it as follows inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726490/overflow-error-in-pythons-numpy-exp-function) answer:

```
def sigmoid(s):
   s = s.astype(np.float128)
   min_value = np.finfo(s.dtype).min
   max_value = np.finfo(s.dtype).max
   s[s == np.NINF] = min_value
   s[s == np.inf] = max_value
   return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-s))
```

But this does no effect and I still get the same error, why is it the case?
Thanks

Comment: with which value is it giving the error?

Comment: You could try [sigmoid RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48540589/sigmoid-runtimewarning-overflow-encountered-in-exp)

Comment: @Mntfr it seems like max value if inf, but I updated my solution to account on this instance. but it still gives same error