# Using np.expm1 to compute sigmoid function

Tags: numpy, floating-point

When computing a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), small or large values of x will return 0 and 1 respectively due to lack of floating-point precision. In `numpy`, the function [`np.expm1`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expm1.html) will compute `exp(x)-1` with better precision for extreme values of x. However, an equivalent function for computing `exp(x)+1`, (denominator in sigmoid function), does not exist. I could not figure out how to use `np.expm1` to compute a sigmoid with increased precision at extreme values.  Is there a way to do so?

```
1/(np.exp(-20)+1)==1.0
#False
1/(np.exp(-50)+1)==1.0
# True
```

Comment: There is a special routine for exp(x)-1 because exp(x)-1 is near zero when x is near zero. By the nature of floating-point, when x is near zero, very fine changes can be made in it, and the function exp(x)-1 reflects those changes. In contrast, exp(x)+1 is never near zero for any real x. Very fine changes in x have no effect in the computed result because the floating-point format is not capable of representing the small changes that occur in exp(x)+1 when x is changed by a tiny amount. You will get the same or very nearly the same result by calculating exp(x) and adding 1.

Comment: The first 40 digits of the exact value of `1/(exp(-50)+1)` are `0.9999999999999999999998071250152036082216`.  The closest value expressible as a 64 bit floating point number is 1.0.  If you need higher precision than that, you'll have to use a ilbrary that provides a numerical representation that has more precision than the standard 64 bit floating point numbers.  For example, I used `mpmath` to compute those 40 digits.

Comment: Or, instead of computing `sigmoid(x)` when x > 0, only compute the difference between 1 and `sigmoid(x)`, which, by symmetry, is `sigmoid(-x)`.  For example, `1 - sigmoid(50) = sigmoid(-50) = 1.928749...e-22`.  But then you have to modify the rest of your code to work with this difference.  Whether that is worth the effort (or even possible) depends on what you will do with the value of `sigmoid(x)`.

Comment: By the way, for computing the sigmoid function, I recommend [`scipy.special.expit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html) instead of creating your own implementation based on `exp`; see, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106134/numpy-pure-functions-for-performance-caching/21106536#21106536

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok, I understand now, so obviously the same applies to [`np.log1p`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html)

Answer (score 1):

`np.expm1` mitigates *loss of significance* which occurs when taking the difference between two almost equal numbers (because many significant places will cancel each other the result will have fewer signficant places than the data type could store).

```
1/(np.exp(-50)+1)==1.0
```

is a limitation of the data type, not the algorithm. `floats` cannot resolve a difference from `1.0` as small as `exp(-50)`. Indeed, the nearest floats left and right of `1.0` are

```
>>> np.nextafter(1.0, 0.0)
0.9999999999999999
>>> np.nextafter(1.0, 2.0)
1.0000000000000002
```

indicating a resolution of oom `10^-16`, nowhere near fine enough to discriminate between `1` and `1 +/- exp(-50)`